# Pdf attachment - acdwfmarkupcore.crx error

Tags: autodesk-forge

**Design Automation API - V3**

I want use Forge to :
  upload one pdf file
  attach it to a dwg file 
  convert the pdf with the PdfImport autocad command
  save and download the dwg

but
  the forge process give me an error during the attachment process:

T:\Aces\AcesRoot\23.1\coreEngine\Exe\acdwfmarkupcore.crx cannot find a dll or other file that it needs.

the pdf file is uploaded fine and correctly found

the problem seems to be in the attach process
the attachement is one of our pure api product, who create manualy PdfDefinition and pdfReference

Next question : is it possible to chain the PdfImport Autocad command ??

thanks in advance

Luc

```
    public static void SampleAttach(string fileName, Database database, Transaction transaction)
    {
        DBDictionary nod = (DBDictionary)transaction.GetObject(database.NamedObjectsDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
        string defDictKey = UnderlayDefinition.GetDictionaryKey(typeof(PdfDefinition));

        if (!nod.Contains(defDictKey))
        {
            using (DBDictionary dict = new DBDictionary())
            {
                nod.SetAt(defDictKey, dict);
                transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dict, true);
            }
        }
        DBDictionary pdfDict = (DBDictionary)transaction.GetObject(nod.GetAt(defDictKey), OpenMode.ForWrite);
        BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)transaction.GetObject(database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
        BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)transaction.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite);

        ObjectId idPdfDef;
        using (PdfDefinition pdfDef = new PdfDefinition())
        {
            pdfDef.SourceFileName = fileName;
            pdfDef.ItemName = "1";
            if (pdfDef.Loaded)
            {
                idPdfDef = pdfDict.SetAt(string.Format(@"{0} - {1}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).ToRestrictiveName(), pdfDef.ItemName), pdfDef);
                transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(pdfDef, true);
                using (PdfReference pdf = new PdfReference())
                {
                    pdf.DefinitionId = idPdfDef;
                    pdf.Rotation = 0;
                    pdf.Position = new Point3d(0, 0, 0.0);
                    btr.AppendEntity(pdf);
                    transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(pdf, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry at the moment, PDFIMPORT command is not supported at Forge Design Automation.
Due various license constraints.

Comment: for pdfimport I understand, but my initial question was about a pdf attachment, can you examine  this ?

Comment: Hi luc, all pdf related commands pdfattach,pdfclip,pdfadjust,pdflayer don't work on design automation. if you have strong business case, can you write to Forge Help <forge.help@autodesk.com>, I will check with our PM.